# Automatically apply 2 filters for 2 columns of csv files

Tags: excel, csv

I filter 2 columns of a CSV file, column A and Column B for certain words. Say I apply a text filter: contains "word1" or contains "word2" to Column A. Then I get the results. After that, I remove the filter to Column A then apply the same filter to Column B. The thing is, I don't get the results in Column B, instead, I get the cells in Column A wherein Column B is filter (*confusing*), PHOTOS BELOW:

***Apply filter to Column A, get results in Column A:***

[image]

*The data that I get for this filter are:*

And Word1 you

Word2 is blank

***Apply filter to Column B, get the cells filtered in Column A:***
[image]

*The data that get for this filter are from Column A (which are cells filtered from Column B filter)*

And Word1 you

Is the blah

Word is all

The results should in a single Column for both filter:

[image]

I have more than 100 files that needs to filtered this way, is there any way I can do this automatically?

Here is what the file looks like:

[image]

The results I hope would be possible:

> Automatically without having to open all the files and have the results of all of it in 1 single Excel file?

----or----

> If the above is not possible, open each file and automatically apply the filter into a column in just 1 click and without having to type the same filter for each column.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: I found a macro than can combine multiple CSV's into 1 Excel, which cuts off half of the workload, but half of my files has more than 500k rows and Excel has a limit of 1million+ rows. :(

Comment: That sounds like a lot of data. Have you considered using a database?

Comment: Haven't tried any. I'm thinking of creating a program for this, though, if its not possible in Excel. :(